# Feedback response in linear system

Tags: control-system, feedback, step-response

I have a linear system with transfer function \$G(s)\$ that is connected in negative feedback with a real value gain \$K\$.

Therefore the open loop transfer function is \$K \cdot G(s)\$

and the closed loop transfer function is \$G(s) / (1 + K \cdot G(s))\$

My question is : "is there a way I can obtain the closed loop response of a change on the gain from \$K\$ to \$K + a\$ where \$a\$ is another real value ?"

Edit:
I would like to obtain the response in the time domain where I can see the reaction of the system to the change of the gain from \$K\$ to \$K+a\$.

Comment: The new closed loop response is just what you wrote but with K substituted with K+a. Surely you cannot be asking this?

Comment: Sure, I will edit the question accordingly, I want a response in the time domain where \$a\$ acts as a perturbation on the system.

Comment: With a constant input signal?

Comment: Yes indeed, a constant input different from 0

Comment: Why not use a simulator?

Comment: Yes, so back to my question, how can I obtain this response in a framework like Python scipy or Matlab ?

Comment: Sorry can't help you with those.

Comment: What do you recommend ?

Comment: I can only tell you that I use a circuit simulator called micro-cap 12 (free now) and that it can be used with laplace terms i.e. you can create blocks with all manner of s terms inside. Then I would abruptly change "a" and see how the output response changed.

Comment: It’s worth a try ! Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Just use the feedback function: https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/feedback.html

Answer (score 2):

> *What do you recommend ? – user185674*

I can only tell you that I use a circuit simulator called micro-cap 12 (free now) and that it can be used with laplace terms i.e. you can create blocks with all manner of s terms inside. Then I would abruptly change "a" and see how the output response changed.

For instance, here's a simple example of a 2nd order low pass filter with 1:1 negative feedback fed from a 1 volt biased square wave of 1 Hz: -

[image]

And the transient response looks like this: -

[image]

You can add "K" within the feedback loop and then make K suddenly rise to K+a and see how the response changes. See example below: -

[image]

I've added a multiplier in the feedback loop fed from a battery that sets the multiplication value to K+a. But, there's no reason whay the battery cannot be replaced by a voltage source that stepped from a value of K to K+a.

And, just in case anyone doubts micro-cap's ability to perform this sort of task, here's a pretty picture from the sales blurb: -

[image]

Comment: I must say, what you are doing is definitely weird. It’s like using a circuit simulator to evaluate sin(0.1). You can do it, but it doesn’t mean you should. Circuit simulators do not have the functionality necessary to analyze and design control systems in a straight forward manner. There are other packages developed to do that.

Comment: @user110971 - then you are not familiar with micro-cap's ability to simulate s and z transforms. I suggest that you take a deeper look before making sweeping judgments. And note the "LF" inside E1 - it stands for Laplace Function.

Comment: The ability to use Laplace sources is not enough. There is a lot more that goes into control engineering. Just off the top of my head, pole placement will be difficult to do in micro cap. For example, designing a deadbeat controller for a DC motor requires the steps of: transform the Laplace open loop transfer function to state-space; digitize to the discrete state-space model; and do pole placement. You can do the easy stuff like the step response in micro cap, but eventually you’ll encounter a wall you can’t go over.

Comment: Please feel free to leave an answer to the question and explain your preferences @user110971

Comment: Fair point. I should put my money where my mouth is. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with the use of the feedback command in MATLAB or any other similar package. Here is a simple example.

```matlab
% open loop transfer function 1 / (s^2 + s + 1)
sys = tf(1, [1 1 1]);

% feedback gains 0.2, 0.4, ..., 1
K = 0.2:0.2:1;

% time vector for the step response
t = 0:0.01:10;

figure;
hold on;
grid on;

% loop over all the gains
for i = 1:length(K)

  % step response
  y = step(t, feedback(sys, K(i)));
  plot(t, y);
end

% create the legend
legend(num2str(K', 'K = %-d'));
```

You get the following output.

[image: step response]

Comment: The op is asking that with a steady input and changing K, what might change.

Comment: If that is the case, then talking about Laplace transforms is incorrect. Since the system will be time varying, and there will be no Laplace transform of its closed loop (at least not one that simplifies solving for the output), like the one of the form $$ \frac{G(s)}{1+K(s)G(s)}$$

Comment: @jDAQ talking about Laplace isn't incorrect if all you have is H(s). You have no option but to talk about Laplace.

Comment: @Andyaka I misunderstood OP’s question. However, a “closed loop response” doesn’t make any sense. The system becomes non-linear. So you won’t be able to make any conclusions from the response other than for the specific input and output of the plant. Definitely smells like an XY problem.

Comment: Behind the scene, I think the op is trying to detect whether the system becomes unstable or not. If that is the case (guesswork) then the problem may indeed be XY @user110971

Comment: @Andyaka you don't have \$H(s)\$ and calculating it will be extremely hard using Laplace transforms, you have this $$ y(t) = (r(t)-k(t)y(t)) \ast g(t) $$ and this $$ Y(s) = (R(s)-K(s) \ast Y(s))G(s)$$ so Laplace transform is the wrong tool to solve this problem, it won't make the problem any easier to solve due to the product k(t)y(t) which becomes a convolution in the Laplace domain. The OP would also be wrong in saying that the 'closed loop transfer function is...' because the closed-loop TF will not be the trivial $$ H(s) = \frac{G(s)}{1+K(s)G(s)}.$$

Comment: @user110971 the system remains linear, it is just not time-invariant.

Comment: Excuse me but the op says this: *I have a linear system with transfer function G(s)*. This means he knows the TF. I don't know the TF but that is irrelevant. My answer was just an example so that the OP could put in his TF.

Comment: @jDAQ No, the system is not linear because you have multiplication involving the inputs. The gain K is actually an input to OP’s system. A linear system must satisfy \$f(a, b) = f(a, 0) + f(0, b)\$. So the response of one of the inputs becomes dependent on the other input (K). Hence the above condition is not satisfied.

Comment: @user110971 That's fair, but I wouldn't consider k(t) as an input the way the OP described the change in the parameter, because it would mean solving a very generic problem. I would consider it as a varying parameter and would model it as a linear time-invariant system for a few different k(t), which is more tractable.

Comment: @jDAQ from what I can deduce from your answers, the system indeed becomes non-linear and there is no closed form of the transfer function to get a response of a step on K. I guess the only way is to use a simulation tool like Andyaka recommended and force an abrupt change on K when the system is at equilibrium to see the response. I was hoping there was a way of putting the problem to obtain some sort of "perturbation response" like in standard dx/dt = Ax + Bu + Dv problems.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry, I didn't mean to sound rude, but, if the OP wants the dynamically changing k(t) and all that, your simulation approach is correct and this one is not. And in that case, talking about a Laplace transform of the whole system is not useful (the OP will not be able to find a TF), even though you can describe as TF G(s) and K(s).

Comment: @jDAQ Yes, you can do that, but it is not very useful. When we do a step response we want to draw some conclusions about the system in general. We expect the response to a step of different size to be similar. For a linear dynamic system the initial conditions need to be set at the point when you do the transition. You get a step response at that point. But this is not just the output of the black box. A system of order N will have N initial conditions. So it’s not enough to know the output. Consider an LC circuit. The initial conditions are the capacitor voltage and the inductor current.

Comment: @jDAQ So you get a certain dependence on the amount of time you let the system to evolve before switching the transfer function. You can have two situations where the input and the output of the plant look the same but you’ll obtain two different step responses. So you can no longer make the generalized conclusions from the step response. You can do all that, if you transform the system to the state space representation in MATLAB. The lsim function has initial conditions that you can specify as an optional input. But, again, this seems like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep things simple and assume that GH(s) is a 2 pole transfer function then you could use a Root Locus technique but calculating the pole values at only 2 values of K. Once the positions of the poles on the s-plane are known then Wn & damping factor (zeta) can be obtained. Then all the standard equations for a 2 pole step response in the time domain can be used to calculate %overshoot, rise time, settling time, number of oscillations, subsidence ratio, peak time.

All these time domain performance characteristics depend on either zeta or zeta & Wn.